# Parallel.ForEach Error showing dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, parallel-processing

this method - doDayBegin(item.BranchId) is taking long time to execute. so i am using Parallel.ForEach to execute it parallel. when i am using normal foreach loop its working fine but when i am using Parallel.ForEach it showing this error

**The context cannot be used while the model is being created  Parallel.ForEach**

```
 public ActionResult Edit([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<DB0010020Vm> _listDB0010020Vm = new List<DB0010020Vm>();

                string dataDB0010020vm = Request.Form["griddetailsvm"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataDB0010020vm))
                {
                    _listDB0010020Vm = js.Deserialize<List<DB0010020Vm>>(dataDB0010020vm).
                    Where(d => d.IsValid == "YES").ToList();
                }
                DateTime start = DateTime.UtcNow;


                Parallel.ForEach(_listDB0010020Vm, item =>
                {
                    doDayBegin(item.BranchId);
                });

                DateTime end = DateTime.UtcNow;
                TimeSpan duration = end - start;
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = true,
                    message = "Day Begin Process Completed Successfully!" + duration
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = e.Message
                });

            }
        }

 public void doDayBegin(int BranchId)
        {

            using (var dbThread = new NeoSampleDBEntities()) // new db connection
            {


                EBS.DAL.Model.DB0010020 branchDetails = _idDB0010020Repository.FindOne(d => d.BranchId == BranchId);
            if (branchDetails == null)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Branch not found!");
            }
            else
            {
                branchDetails.LastOpenDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["LastOpenDate"]);

                OperationStatus status = _idDB0010020Repository.UpdateAndSave(branchDetails);
                if (status != null && !status.Status)
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Updation failed", status.ExceptionMessage);
            }

            EBS.DAL.Model.DB0010044 dayBegin = new DB0010044();
            dayBegin.BankId = 1;
            dayBegin.BranchId = BranchId;
            dayBegin.DayBeginFlag = 1;
            dayBegin.DayDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Form["LastOpenDate"]);
            dayBegin.DayEndFlag = 0;
            dayBegin.DayEndStage = 1;
            dayBegin.DayReopenFlag = 0;
            OperationStatus status2 = _idDB0010044Repository.AddAndSave(dayBegin);
            if (status2 != null && !status2.Status)
                ModelState.AddModelError("Updation failed", status2.ExceptionMessage);
            else
            {
                CreateInwardSessionsForBranch(BranchId);
                CreateOutwardSessionsForBranch(BranchId);
            }
            }
        }
```

this is error
[image: this error i am getting]

what will be the issue?

Comment: What's in the doDayBegin method.

Comment: doDayBegin method added in quesion @RonaldEstacion

Comment: Move the var dbThread = new NeoSampleDBEntities(); on the class level, and only dispose it once the parallel action is completed.

Comment: @RonaldEstacion I am not using this line anywhere i was added this for testin purpose.

Comment: what i mean is create a field outside the method, private NeoSampleDBEntities dbThread = new NeoSampleDBEntities();, now use it without the using() block in the doDayBegin method. I'm guessing that the parallel execution is disposing the context before the other call in FindOne is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a new instance of the `NeoSampleDBEntities` `DbContext` in the `doDayBegin` method, but you use an existing (and as far as I can tell, single) instance of the repository `_idDB0010020Repository`, presumably encapsulating its own instance of `DbContext` or a pre-existing `DbContext` instance that was passed in on construction.

The error you're seeing is the result of a second thread's call to `<repo>.FindOne` making a `DbContext` method call while the model is being generated as a result of the first thread's call to `<repo>.FindOne`.  Even if the model creation finished, you'll more than likely run into conflicts as `DbContext` is not thread safe.

From what you've posed, my suggestion would be to create a new repo in the `using` statement of the `doDayBegin` method instead of a new instance of the `NeoSampleDBEntities` `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it's that _listDB0010020Vm has not been calculated yet when the parallel.foreach is called.   If you step through the code in a standard non parallel foreach, it would show this by skipping the .where selection line,  going into the foreach, then when it needs the list value,  step next will show it jump back to the where selector.  I believe List.ToArray will force it to calculate.  Try paying that result to the parallel loop.